# What does this part mean in find command with -exec \{\}?

Tags: shell-script, find, ksh

I have this command (KSH)

```
find <path> -regextype posix-extended -type f -regex '.*/txt' -exec ls -l --full-time \{\} \;
| sort -bnr
```

So, I'm reading and deciphering the command above so far what I know is that

```
-regextype posix-extended
```

this just changes the regextype to posix-extended

```
-type f
```

this only return files

```
-regex '.*/txt'
```

this is just regular expression

```
-exec ls -l --full-time
```

executes `ls -l --full-time`

```
\\{\\}
```

this one I don't get. What does it do? What I know is that I need to end `-exec` with `{} \;` but why there's backslash inside the curly braces?

Comment: @muru Thank you! I guess I never looked enough in the man page to see this. smh. PS. I don't know how to upvote your comment though :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I know is that I need to end `-exec` with `{} \;` but why there's backslash inside the curly braces?

The backslashes remove the special meaning of the following character, like here:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ echo \$SHELL
$SHELL
```

That's what they do here, too, except that in sh-like shells `{}` isn't special to begin with, so they're not needed. They would be needed in at least the fish shell, where the plain `{}` gets removed, or if you had something that looks like a brace expansion in Bash/ksh/zsh, but didn't want to expand it. (e.g. `echo \{foo,bar\}` vs `echo {foo,bar}`)

Answer (score 0):

The {} get substituted by the entities found by find. 
At least in bash the escaping of the {} is not nessesary so a 
`...-exec ls -l --full-time {} \;` might work as well.